# Themes in Safari

Tags: safari, windows, safari-windows

I have themes in almost every browser that I have installed on my PC. Most themes on the Internet are absolute crap - blurry, inappropriate, racist, or all three. However, I've always managed to get some good theme that I'm happy with.

However, with Safari, it's a different story. I have no clue how to install themes.

Several different sites have said several different things. Some have said that it's as  easy as editing a file. Others said that themes aren't supported and will crash Safari.

Can I get themes for Safari running on Windows? And if so, how?

Comment: "Most themes on the Internet are absolute crap" -- so is adding theming and skinning to every piece of software. :)

Comment: @Ian C.: Some browsers are really improved by a good theme. Some are not. IMHO, customization is awesome if done right. You don't need to skin your calculator with a bright neon glowing animated ghost theme that moves around the screen, but when you spend a large amount of your time in front of a browser (as I do) theming or skinning can improve that experience.

Comment: Can you show me a theme for a browser, let's say Chrome, that proves your point? I posit that no such theme exists.